# SQL Server, selecting random item from table where id used across another table

Tags: sql-server, join, random

Given the simple database structure:

```
Account
   - Id (Primary Key)

Root
   - Id (Primary Key)
   - AccountId (FK to Account)
   - Private (bit)

RootItem
   - Id (Primary Key)
   - AccountId (FK to Account)
   - RootId (FK to Root)
```

Does anyone know how I can write a SQL statement to do the following?

Given the fact I only know someone's Account.Id as int, lets say @AccountId = 1.
Select a **random** Root record which has **no** attached RootItem records that have an AccountId that = @AccountID and where Root.Private = 0.

This is for SQL Server, any help would be appreciated, I'm not all that good with SQL joins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select top 1 *
from
    Root r
        left join
    RootItem ri
        on
            r.Id = ri.RootID and
            ri.AccountId = @AccountID
where
    r.Private = 0 and
    ri.Id is null
order by
    newid()
```

To eliminate Roots which have RootItems that match the account ID, we do the left join above, but then in the where clause, we ensure (ri.Id is null) that no match actually occurred. To select a row randomly, we're ordering by newid(), which will generate a new GUID for each row, and then just selecting the top 1.

If we need a stronger source of randomness, or some good statistical properties, we may have to look at working in CLR.

Comment: Very nice, perfect use for `NEWID()`. +1